# Magento 2.4.3-p1 : Deprecated Functionality: Return type of Magento\Framework\DataObject::offsetExists($offset)

Tags: php, magento

When I try to execute access my website in developer mode

I get an exception as

> Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Return type of Magento\Framework\DataObject::offsetExists($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject.php on line 513

Does anyone have solution for this?

Thank You.

Comment: Its warning you, you will need to change your code to remain compliant with the next version of the software

Comment: I am using PHP version 7.4.28 and in Magento system requirements showing 7.4 is compatible with Magento 2.4.3

Comment: Yes, but a deprecation notice is there to let you know ahead of time that a change will be coming in, normally, the next major release